# how does Mapreduce on KFS happen?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I wanted to understand how mapreduce happens using KFS as file system in Hadoop.

> > # ./bin/start-mapred.sh
> >      If the map/reduce job/task trackers are up, all I/O will be done to KFS.

So, suppose my input files are scattered in different nodes(Kosmos servers), how do I(hadoop client using KFS as file system) issue a Mapreduce command?

Moreover, after issuing a Mapreduce command would my hadoop client fetch all the data from different servers to my local machine and then do a Mapreduce or would it start the TaskTracker daemons on the machine(s) where the input file(s) are located and perform a Mapreduce there?
Please rectify me if I am wrong but I suppose that the location of input files top Mapreduce is being returned by the function getFileBlockLocations (FileStatus, long, long).

Thank you very much for your time and helping me out.

Regards,
Nikhil

Comment: are you mentioning Kosmos File system(KFS)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the reply but i am still not clear where is Mapreduce actually happening?

Comment: Chk my Updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. MapReduce is a program that is run in all the nodes, in a distributed fashion. The Master node will be like a supervisor for all the data/slave nodes responsible for the get the work done.
[image: Fig :1]

**Map Reduce Tasks**

- A MapReduce job usually splits the input data-set into independent
  chunks which are processed by the map tasks in a completely parallel
  manner.
- The framework sorts the outputs of the maps, which are then input to 
  the reduce tasks.
- Typically both the input and the output of the job are stored in a
  file-system.
- The framework takes care of scheduling tasks, monitoring them and
  re-executes the failed tasks.

[image: Fig: 2]
[image: Fig: 3]
The Above fig:3 shows How the MapReduce happens at node level.

**Now your about your KFS:**

When the Hadoop map/reduce trackers start up, those processes (on local as well as remote nodes) will now need to load KFS's libkfsClient.so library.

To simplify this process, it is advisable to store `libkfsClient.so` in an NFS accessible directory (similar to where Hadoop binaries/scripts are stored); then, modify Hadoop's conf/hadoop-env.sh adding the following line and providing suitable value for

```
<path>:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path>
```

Chk out this link: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/kfs/package-summary.html

Comment: Here the Output file explained in the figure 2, is also stored in the KFS/HDFS in a distributed system.

Comment: Hi!! Thanks a lot for putting in so much of effort to answer my question. The diagram explains quite well how a MapReduce actually happens. In Hadoop there are different FileSystems like HDFS/KFS/S3/etc. In case of S3 the data is fetched to the local machine and then MR is done on it. continued in comment below......

Comment: Therefore, I wanted to ask that in case of KFS, is the data pulled from different servers to the local machine ? or Does the MR framework start TaskTracker daemons on the nodes containing the input data for MR and thus, MR is carried out without any fetching of data? The link which you had specified i have seen but it does not clearly answer the question. Thanks for your time and energy.

Comment: I would still say it works the same for GFS,HDFS or KFS(cloudstore) Because most of the places KFS is just another option and nothing specifically has been mentioned unlike S3, they all work on local computation and  grouping only computed data is shuffled for reduce process.